# Finding the best way to Process (Fetching/ Modifying) a nested Object in JS/TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the below Object. I want to add an additional property for example "category": "I don't have any child"
to all those children objects (with name "some name 111, some name 222 ....") who don't have any children

```
{
            "name":"Grand Parent",
            "children":[
                {
                "name":"Parent 1",
                "children":[
                    {
                        "name":"some name 111",
                        "qty":1                         
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"some name 222",
                        "qty":1
                    }
                ]
                },
                {
                    "name":"Parent 2",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "name":"some name 333",
                            "qty":1
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"some name 444",
                            "qty":1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name":"Parent 3",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "name":"some name 555",
                            "qty":1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name":"Parent 4",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "name":"some name 666",
                            "qty":1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `forEach`, with an object that is checked for children. If it is not present then `child['category'] = "I don't have any child"` can be added to the object. This is customized for only two levels of depth (as asked in the question).

```
data.children.forEach(parent => {
  if (!parent.children)
    parent['category'] = "I don't have any child"
  else
    parent.children.forEach(child => {
      if (!child.children)
        child['category'] = "I don't have any child"
    })
})
```

**Code Snippet:**

```js
const data = { "name": "Grand Parent", "children": [{ "name": "Parent 1", "children": [{ "name": "some name 111", "qty": 1 }, { "name": "some name 222", "qty": 1 }] }, { "name": "Parent 2", "children": [{ "name": "some name 333", "qty": 1 }, { "name": "some name 444", "qty": 1 }] }, { "name": "Parent 3", "children": [{ "name": "some name 555", "qty": 1 }] }, { "name": "Parent 4", "children": [{ "name": "some name 666", "qty": 1 }] }] }

data.children.forEach(parent => {
  if (!parent.children)
    parent['category'] = "I don't have any child"
  else
    parent.children.forEach(child => {
      if (!child.children)
        child['category'] = "I don't have any child"
    })
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: This could work as long as the data is guaranteed to be exactly two levels deep, but might otherwise require a recursive function to dive as deep as necessary. Also, I'd recommend using `forEach` instead of `map` since you're not returning anything from the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a recursive function that adds a property to an object if it has no `children` prop and, otherwise, calls that same recursive function on each element in its `children` array.

```js
const obj = { "name":"Grand Parent", "children":[ { "name":"Parent 1", "children":[ { "name":"some name 111", "qty":1
}, { "name":"some name 222", "qty":1 } ] }, { "name":"Parent 2", "children":[ { "name":"some name 333", "qty":1 }, { "name":"some name 444", "qty":1 } ] }, { "name":"Parent 3", "children":[ { "name":"some name 555", "qty":1 } ] }, { "name":"Parent 4", "children":[ { "name":"some name 666", "qty":1 } ] } ] };

function checkChildren(obj) {
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
    obj.category = "I have no children";
  } else {
    obj.children.forEach(child => {
      checkChildren(child);
    })
  }
}

checkChildren(obj);

console.log(obj);
```